# SQL Server : An invalid floating point operation occurred

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, floating-point

```
Declare @adjustedCurve float
Declare @difLog float
Declare @power float
Declare @valueToAdjust float = 38853.587145
Declare @lastValue float = 44930.63473
Declare @expValue float = 39446.17143


Set @difLog = log(@lastValue) -log(@expValue)
Set @power = exp(@difLog)
Set @adjustedCurve = @power  * @valueToAdjust 

Select @adjustedCurve
```

This takes part of a function, that is used on a query.
I know this works fine by itself, but not in the context of the query.

The error is not in `@diflog` or `@power` (I tested separately, and they work fine).
The problem is with the final multiplication.
All values are `float`. But I tested with `decimal(15,5)` and the problem remains.

Any ideas?

Comment: I get a syntax error for your SQL; though we don't know what values of your variables are so we can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: `log(@value1))` isn't syntactically valid nor well balanced. If you could reproduce it in a [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) that would help us help you. Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: What do you mean by not well balance? I corrected the code. It is just an extract of a much larger function included in a query.

Comment: Your SQL does not generate the error you say it does: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d91b486da9bf43c674ffcc7fad9ce5c5)

Comment: I know that. But it still generates an error in the context of a large query. Specifically, the final multiplication to get @adjustedCurve. The values are exactly the same are those that generate the error.

Comment: Are you sure you are not seeing the last calculation that worked prior to the error?

Comment: I would look for any lastValue or expValue that is zero or less.  Perhaps put a test for these and do a raiserror before the calculation.

Comment: *"I know that."* Then what is that SQL if it isn't the SQL that generates the problem? Provide a [mre].

Comment: If this function is used in a where clause (groan), it might be evaluated for all rows.  Bad data in any row could cause this.  We need more context to be of much more help.

Answer (score 1):

I do not get the error.  I suspect the issue is elsewhere.  Anyway, you are doing extra calculation.

```
exp(x-y) = exp(x)/exp(y)

exp(log(x)) = x
```

Try replacing the calculation with just

```
Set @adjustedCurve = @lastValue * @valueToAdjust / @expValue
```

If there is a chance of overflow (unlikely), you can divide first.

```
Set @adjustedCurve = @lastValue / @expValue * @valueToAdjust
```

Comment: The new calculation will tolerate negative values.  The results will not be identical in that it will not error for some values that would be an issue for log.

Comment: As you said, the error must be somewhere else. I simplified the math but got the same issue.

Comment: If all else fails, you can add RAISERROR('Made it to label %s', 10, 1, 'spot 42') WITH NOWAIT statements at various points in the code.